# maven configuration tag value's set null in java code if "plugin" tag add inside "pluginManagement" (look following code)

Tags: java, maven

**pom.xml**

```
<pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.example.groupid</groupId>
                <artifactId>artifact-example-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>mojo-plugin-id</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>example-gole</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>integration-test</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <employee>
                                <firstName>MyFirstName</firstName>
                                <middleName>MyMiddleName</middleName>
                                <lastName>MyLastName</lastName>
                            </employee>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
```

***above configuration tag value set as null in java class (java class as follow), But if I removed "pluginManagement" tag everything works fine***

**ExampleMojo.java**

```
@Mojo(name = "example-gole")
```

public class ExampleMojo extends AbstractMojo {

```
@Parameter(property = "employee")
private Employee employee; 

@Override
public void execute() throws MojoExecutionException {
    getLog().info(employee);
}
```

}

***execute method show null output to all properties***

**Employee.java**

```
public class Employee implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private String firstName;
private String middleName;
private String lastName;

// consider constructor, getter and setter, hashcode, eqauls, toString is available
```

}

**More Info**

Creating customized maven plugin, above java classes are from maven plugin but the above pom.xml configuration from its caller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**It's working for me now. Used "plugin" "configuration" tag instead of "execution" "configuration" tag**

```
<pluginManagement>
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>com.example.groupid</groupId>
        <artifactId>artifact-example-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>mojo-plugin-id</id>
                <goals>
                    <goal>example-gole</goal>
                </goals>
                <phase>integration-test</phase>
            </execution>
        </executions>

        <configuration>
            <employee>
                <firstName>MyFirstName</firstName>
                <middleName>MyMiddleName</middleName>
                <lastName>MyLastName</lastName>
            </employee>
        </configuration>

    </plugin>
</plugins>
```